# HttpInterceptor With HttpModule

Tags: angular, http

In my angular application (angular version 5), I am using `Http` from `@angular/http`. And also I am appending headers in a normal way like

```
getHeaders(){
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('authorization', 'Bearer '+this.authToken);
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return headers;
}
```

Now I want to change this way and thought to use `HttpInterceptor`. As I know, We have to use it with `HttpClient` but in my angular application. I have used `Http` so far. Is there any way that we can implement `HttpInterceptor` with `Http`.

Comment: Angular version ?

Comment: Angular version 5. I will update my question.

Comment: You can always extends Http and add interception before every call - not much of effort.

Comment: It will be a lot of effort if you're still using **@angular/http** to implement HttpInterceptor, and is not recommended to use anymore as it is already deprecated https://angular.io/api/http, so better use HttpClient, because in the long run upgrading your project would be very difficult

Comment: @JohnVelasquez till now Http didn't give me any problem. Its working fine, but I have more than 10 components. It will be quite difficult, I am already so far in this project.

Comment: @JohnVelasquez What should I do now, I also need to do changes at the response side because I am mapping the responses also.

Comment: I don't know how to implement HttpInterceptor using **@angular/http**, but i can recommend you to try to make a service which is a common-ajax service for all http verbs, and instead calling Http in your repository service, use the common-ajax

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can simulate Http interceptor with Http module.

```js
// create interceptor service

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Http,
  ConnectionBackend,
  RequestOptions,
  RequestOptionsArgs,
  Response,
  Headers,
  Request
} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

// Shows Progress bar and notifications
import { NotifyService } from "./loader";

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {

  constructor(
    backend: ConnectionBackend,
    defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
    private notifyService: NotifyService
  ) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  // for get method
  
   get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
    this.beforeRequest();
    return super.get(this.getFullUrl(url), this.customizeOptions(options))
      .catch(console.log('Ouch!!!'))
      .do((res: Response) => {
        console.log('Nothing can stop me');
      }, (error: any) => {
        console.log("I'm hit. where's my medicccc : - X");
      })
      .finally(() => {
        console.log('Finally we Won the war :-)')
      });
  }
  // write for post method here 
  
  // some other methods you can write here 
  
  // to handle error
  private onError(error: any): void {
    this.notifyService.popError();
  }

  private onFinally(): void {
    this.responseInterceptor();
  }
}
```

Now in `app.module` do following :(note that  : HttpInterceptor is imported from the file you have created)

```
 providers: [
    NotifyService,
    {
      provide: HttpInterceptor,
      useFactory:
        (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, notifyService: NotifyService) => {
        return new HttpInterceptor(backend, defaultOptions, notifyService);
      },
      deps: [ XHRBackend, RequestOptions, LoaderService, Store]
    }
```

and modify your  service file  :

```
/ imports here 
// .......

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(public http: HttpInterceptor) {};
getData() {
    return this
      .http.get(`data?limit=20&offset=40`)
      // will hit the api on http://api.localhost.com:4000/data?limit=20&offset=40
      .map(res => res.json().data)
  }

}
```